# Moving object of lists in C++ to another object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand how this piece of code is working.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct complex
{
  int n;
  std::string str;
  complex(int n): n(n), str("String form " + std::to_string(n)) {}
};

struct Node
{
    Node(){std::cout<<"creating obj\n";}
    Node(const Node &a){ll = a.ll; pll = a.pll;}
    Node(Node &&a){ll = std::move(a.ll); pll = std::move(a.pll);}
    Node& operator=(const Node &a){ll = a.ll; pll = a.pll; return *this;}
    Node& operator=(Node &&a){ll = std::move(a.ll); pll = std::move(a.pll); return *this;}

    ~Node()
    {
      std::cout<<"Destroying object\n";
      for(auto iter : ll)
      {
        iter = 0;
      }
      for(auto iter : pll)
      {
        delete(iter);
        iter = nullptr;
      }
    }

    std::list<int> ll;
    std::list<complex*> pll;
};

Node CreateNode()
{
    Node n;
    n.ll.push_back(1);
    n.ll.push_back(2);
    n.ll.push_back(3);
    n.ll.push_back(4);
    n.ll.push_back(5);
    n.ll.push_back(6);
    n.ll.push_back(7);

    n.pll.push_back(new complex(11));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(21));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(31));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(41));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(51));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(61));
    n.pll.push_back(new complex(71));

    return std::move(n);
}

int main()
{
  Node m;

  std::cout<<"Before assigning Nodes\n";
  for(auto iter : m.ll)
  {
      std::cout<<iter<<" ";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
  for(auto iter : m.pll)
  {
      std::cout<<iter->n<<", "<<iter->str<<" --> ";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";

  m = CreateNode();

  std::cout<<"After assigning Nodes\n";
  for(auto iter : m.ll)
  {
      std::cout<<iter<<" ";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
  for(auto iter : m.pll)
  {
      std::cout<<iter->n<<", "<<iter->str<<" --> ";
  }
  std::cout<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

In the copy constructor or in the copy assignment operator, I'm just passing the list, which has a discrete memory allocation. How is it possible that passing only the **a.pll** in my move semantics moves the whole lot of the memory to the next object? I expected I need to go though each of the list objects and then move them across.

But No. It is simply working like magic, just by moving **a.pll** to other object. How is going on internally?

You can see this in action here:
https://repl.it/repls/WildComfortableLesson

Comment: Encapsulation is Magic. Sometimes it is the Dark Magic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because [`std::list` implements move assignment for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/operator%3D).

By the way, the move constructor can be improved a bit by using initializer lists:

```
Node(Node&& n) : ll{std::move(n.ll)}, pll{std::move(n.pll)} {}
```

This will move construct the two lists (using `std::list`'s move constructor), instead of default constructing and then move assigning them. The same holds for the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I see a `Node m` being made which contains two empty lists. List one contains ints list 2 contains an int and string. Then when you call function CreateNode it simply goes through the empty node and assigns values one by one (see the create Node function) ( could have used a loop for this but instead in this implementation they just pushed one by one ( same thing )). Then they print the values.

I hope this helps cheers.